# Let f : R → R be continuous and let A = {x ∈ R : f(x) ≥ 0}. Show that A is closed in R and conclude that A is complete.

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

Trying to prove this is closed by showing its complement is open by using the fact that f is continuous but I'm not able to work it out at all.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Preimage of closed set under continuous map is closed.Can you conclude now?

Comment: Let U = { f(x) : f(x) ≥ 0},  then $U^c$ = { f(x) : f(x) < 0 },  therefore $U^c$ is an open set as it is just all f(x) ∈ R such that f(x) < 0 and this is just the interval     (-∞,o). Then $U$ is closed as $U^c$ is open. A = $f^-1$(U) so is also closed because f is continuous.

Comment: @Eoin seems fine to me.Bravo!